# Kannel SqlBox configuration failed

Tags: kannel

I am trying to install sqlbox. I have already installed kannel. I have gwlib in the /usr/include/kannel. I am running the below command :-

./configure --with-kannel-dir=/usr/include/kannel

I am getting below error at the end :-

checking for cfg_create in -lgwlib... no
configure: error: Kannel gwlib is required!

In /usr/include/kannel I have below files and directories :- 
gw  gw-config.h  gwlib  wap

Someone please help...

Answer (score 2):

Re-Compile your kannel. As given below:-
./configure --with-mysql

make

make install

After recompiling the kannel. Then installed sqlbox!!
It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure --with-kannel-dir points to the correct kannel installation dir
As a rule of thumb .. this should be the same folder as the folder that contains kannel binaries

For example if this is used to install kannel

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/kannel
make
make bindir=/usr/local/kannel install
```

Install sqlbox like this

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/kannel --with-kannel-dir=/usr/local/kannel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest sqlboxfrom the trunk

```
$ svn co https://svn.kannel.org/gateway/trunk
$ cd trunk
$ ./configure --with-mysql
$ make
$ make install
$ cd addons/sqlbox
$ ./configure --with-kannel=/usr/local/include/kannel
$ make
$ make install
```